# Restrict the maximum number of independent IP connection on specific port at the same time

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, account-restrictions

I set up a server as a socks5 proxy.
I'd like restrict the maximum number(1 or 5 or 20) independent IP connection on specific port at the same time.
I have searched on google, only see some articles like [Iptables Limits Connections Per IP](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-connection-limits-howto/)(talk about Limit SSH Connections Per IP / Host) or [Limit maximum incoming connections to a port using iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/371763/limit-maximum-incoming-connections-to-a-port-using-iptables) and so on. 
They all use `iptables connlimit moudle`, just limit the number of connections on a port (one IP can have several connections, but do not restrict the amount of ip, no use)
So these do not fit my need.

**update**
Let me explain my purpose more accurately.
I want a port only allow a fixed number(1 or 5 or 20) of IP to connect.Not limit connection from per IP.
 
I think there may be many way to do this.
First thing I thought is iptables, but it seems not capable to my job(I don't know, maybe someone can use iptables achieve my goal, so I ask this question).
I have thought another way too.I can use a program monitor every port, if it find a port which connection IP number exceed the `preset value`, then it shut down the extra connections to keep current IP number equal or less `preset value`.But I don't know which program can do this.
It's welcome if you have another approach to solve my problem. Just not be trapped by iptables.